# How can I model this scenario in a graph database?

Tags: database, schema, graph-databases

I'm developing an application where users can tag resources and it's also important to know who tagged the resource with a specific tag.

A graph database seems like a good fit for this and the rest of the application but having only previously used traditonal RDBMSs I'm struggling to see how to model this scenario.

I a relational database I would have a "PersonResourceTag" join table to identify which user applied a particular tag, but with a graph database I can't work out how to associate the person with a tag for a specific resource. Would I need some kind of "PersonTaggedResource" vertex or is there a better way? ...or is this simply not a good fit for a graph database?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Graph Databases are in general, a superset of what an RDBMS can do. The implementations are completely different and you have to forget all the RDBMS idioms when you approach using a Graph Database. The *relationships* are not modeled with a *join table*, they are modeled directly into the node with a *relationship". This is called *index free adjacency*, which is the exact opposite of a join table in an RDBMS.

```
Person -> Tags[Tag] -> Resource
```

Where `Tag` is a `Property` and the above syntax is very close to the actual GraphQL syntax to query the graph with.

You can get a free copy of [Graph Databases from O'reilly](http://neo4j.com/books/graph-databases/?utm_source=GPPC&gclid=Cj0KEQjwsIWvBRCnzevvor2g4L8BEiQAAN234WIqXUJzuP8qWRR1CYRmhmstGkrZbYLgtMNKTEeoNmIaAmV58P8HAQ), it is a great read.